# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization

Tags: javascript, api

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization`

I am trying to call an API but was told to put this in my code but I keep getting the error above. What can I do to fix this?

```
    let data = await(await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrer: 'no-referrer',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })).json();
    DisplayResponce(data);
```

Comment: What is `data` intended to refer to in the line `body: JSON.stringify(data)`? You can't reference an object that hasn't been created yet

Comment: i was told to do this @CertainPerformance

Comment: Ok, but can you answer the question? It's hard to tell what your intent is here

Comment: i want to get information from an api and use it on my website

Comment: What is the `data` in `body: JSON.stringify(data)` meant to refer to?

Comment: i dont know i was told to put all of that code in there

Comment: Well, the code's syntax is invalid, so whoever told you to use it is wrong, but without more information on what the `data` is supposed to be, it's not really answerable on what a solution might be

Comment: the 'data' is the api response

Comment: So you want to send the API response as the body, while fetching, before the API response has been retrieved? That doesn't make sense

Comment: i am a beginner with js

Comment: What these others comments are getting at is that you are initializing a variable called `data` (`let data = await fetch(...)`) and then also using that same variable within the fetch itself, hence the error `Cannot access 'data' before initialization`. There's lots of other things wrong with this code sample, such as your double use of `await`, but to specifically answer why you're getting that error, its because you are initializing `data` and also trying to use it before it has finished being initialized.

Comment: yes but if i remove that line of code it gives me another error

Comment: index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://api.mcsrvstat.us/ping/minehut.com' from origin 'http://happy-fone.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call an API, sometimes you need to provide some parameters. In the example call provided to you, the line `body: JSON.stringify(data)` indicates that this is true for the API call you are trying to make.

As user CertainPerformance already pointed out in the comments to the question, the error message points to the `data` in the `body: JSON.stringify(data)` line.

Please refer to the API documentation or contact the API Developer to get information about the expected parameters in order to make the call work.